# Is it possible to play 2 WebRTC streams simultaneously in a single screen via a streaming connection in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, janus, janus-gateway

I have to do this in iOS using Swift.

I am planning to get a video stream from Janus VideoRoom connection which will include video and audio in one stream, for which i will be using Janus gateways for both.

Meanwhile i need to get another stream from Janus AudioBridge, which will be only audio.

Then i have to play them in a single screen simultaneously.

Is it possible in iOS using Swift?

Any help or guidance in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Yes this is is possible